# Is there a faststart equivalent for MP3 files?

Tags: audio, encoding, ffmpeg, mp3, html5-audio

I plan to serve MP3 files on the web using an `audio` element. I heard that when serving video files, it's best to encode with the `faststart` flag. Is there an equivalent for MP3 files? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm a beginner and want to make sure I use the optimal settings because my files are often large (5 MB). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faststart only applies to mp4.

Comment: Thanks @szatmary -- I'm aware of that, which is why I asked if there's the **equivalent** for MP3, something that would speed up the download or something. Any hints are welcome. Cheers!

Comment: @Kerans You file to understand my meaning. I don't mean the "word" fast start only applies to mp4, I mean the "concept" fast start only applies to mp4. mp4 is the only format that allows for headers to be written to the end of the file. "fast start" moves the headers to the start of the file. No other format has this. Mp3 for example is a raw  stream (the bitstream doubles as a container) There simply are no headers to move.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean now @szatmary, thanks a lot for clarifying that. Sorry if I came off as rude, it was misunderstanfging on my part. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it may be worthwhile moving the above clarification into the main answer in order to provide a bit more context. Anyone asking this question is unlikely to be familiar with the way fast start works and header formats in general. Therefore it seems unfair to assume they would have this knowledge in the first place